# Get photos and likes with php via Instagram API

Tags: php, json, instagram, instagram-api

While using an Instagram `client_id` API request like here:

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT_ID

I can actually SEE both the image url and like-count in the JSON response, but can't figure out how to extract both. I can only seem to extract the image itself like so:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['user_id'])){
    $user_id = ($_GET['user_id']);

    // connect to the instagram API
  $instagram_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $user_id . '/media/recent/?client_id=MY-CLIENT-ID';
  $instagram_json = file_get_contents($instagram_url);
  $instagram_array = json_decode($instagram_json, true);
}
?>
```

--

```
<?php
  if(!empty($instagram_array)){
    foreach($instagram_array['data'] as $key=>$image){
      echo '<img src="'.$image['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'" alt=""/><br>';
    }
  }
?>
```

ps - this is all cobbled together from various tutorials etc. I am total noob, so a little hand-holding would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the images count of likes like this: `$image['likes']['count']`