# Instagram API get pictures and likes

Tags: api, instagram-api

**Hello**

First of all, no this is **NOT** a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523008/get-photos-and-likes-with-php-via-instagram-api).

A few months back I was able to get my own instagram pictures and like counts from a public API, however now I'm not able to get any information from that same API because it stopped working (I believe)..

I know how to write the code but what link do I have to use to get my own public pictures and likes, like I did before?

I **NEVER** used a client_id key or auth key for this, but now all over the internet they say that you need these keys. That doesn't make any sense to me.

**Question in short:**

What api link can I use to get my pictures and likes without any keys. If there is no API that does this anymore, why is that?

**Thanks a bunch!**

Comment: whats wrong with using client_id? or doing auth and using token?

Comment: you said you wanted likes as well.

Comment: `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1` would give you pictures

Comment: @enator Oh my god. Thank you so much! I really needed this. Thanks!!

Comment: @enator It seems like the link has been shutdown again... Any other open api link?

Answer (score 0):

So this is the PUBLIC instagram API that anyone can use if a profile is public and **NOT** private.

```
https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1
```

Huge thanks to Enator in the comments. I wasn't able to find anything on Google about this.

Comment: As of May 2018 it seems like the link isn't working anymore.